# Interop between C++ classes inside an WinRT component

Tags: c#, c++, dll, windows-runtime, interop

Currently iam working on a WinRT dll component using native C++ to render directx and like to use this component in a C# project.

The idea is to have one class (for example A) doing the drawing and exposing relevant public methods to WinRT. This is working fine. But now I need a helper class (B) in the dll project with user defined types in public methods. That helper class only needs to be visable inside the dll component and is only used as private member by A. Unfortunately this class B is also exposed to WinRT which means I can not use user defined types/classes in public methods. In short, I like to do something like this:

```
    public ref class A sealed
    {
        public:
            void addRenderData(float ...);

        private:
        B helper;
        ...
    }

    class B
    {
        public:
            void addMeasurement(MyOwnStruct* m);
            AnyC++Type doSomething();
        private:
        ...
    }
```

Is it possible to declare my helper class B in a way, that it is only useable within the dll assembly (which is entirely written in C++) and get rid of "signature of public member contains native type"

I don't like the idea of generating an additional c++ dll for doing calculations which is used by my WinRT component

any help on this topic would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it... very simple indeed, just use the internal keyword! I tried to solve this with this keyword before, but only on class level which was not possible because its a native c++ class. Anyway, when you use internal to members everything is okay:

```
internal:
    list<Line>* getRenderPoints();
```

Now only my DirectX component is exposed as control to WinRT, behind that I can implement the logic nicely in different c++ native classes